# Using mod_rails to host multiple apps under SSL, same domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, apache2, mod-rails

I'm trying to get multiple rails apps hosted under the same domain, but different directories. My configuration before attempting to host multiple apps (which works great), looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName secure.mydomain.com  
    DocumentRoot /root/store/public
</VirtualHost>
```

I google'd around and found documentation suggesting I use the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName secure.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /root
    RailsBaseURI /store/public
    RailsBaseURI /store2/public                
</VirtualHost>
```

That configuration, however, only causes my directory structure to be revealed, and no app appears to run. Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you found on the Googles, but you might want to re-read the mod_rails docs on [Deploying to sub URIs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri)

I'm guessing you'll need to create some symbolic links (aliases) in your `/root` directory to the `public` folder of each application

```
ln -s /store/public /root/store
```